# What is this mushroom attached to the terrarium with transparent cap and black strips?

Tags: species-identification, botany, mycology

I have a terrarium with something black attached to the glass with a whitish green stem. Can someone please help identifying this?

The terrarium is outside in the backyard and receives only direct early morning sunlight -- it's currently summer. Location: Melbourne, Australia.

Terrarium internal side:

[image]

Terrarium external side:

[image: Terrarium External Side]

---

**Update:**

Another exterior picture from the terrarium shows better details from the transparent cap and the black strips:

[image: transparent-cap-black-strips-mushroom]

Comment: you are giving your succulents way to much water and you are giving us too little information.

Comment: @trondhansen, what information can I provide more than the photo?

Comment: what research have you done to try to find an answer to what this might be,where do you live,what temperature is your terrarium,what type of light do you use,for how long has this been growing in your terrarium.

Comment: @trondhansen, I have done enough research to accept being ridiculed at this website. The terrarium is outside at the backyard and receives only direct early morning sunlight. Here in Melbourne is summer.

Comment: this is very usefull information for the one(s)answering your question,please edit this into your question.and you should know that every single site here on SE want all of us to do some research before we ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

I think (I'm definitely no expert) that this is one of the genus *[Parasola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasola)* ([Psathyrellaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psathyrellaceae)), they used to be part of a group that are known as inkcap mushrooms, though I see that this has changed. What gives it away is the thin cap and being able to see  the ribs in the cap looking like the ribs in a [parasol or umbrella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbrella). It could also be one of the closely related *[Coprinellus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprinellus)* or *[Coprinopsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Coprinopsis_species)*, but these seem to have a thicker, less umbrella-like cap.

There are a number of species, and without access to spores and a spore print it would be impossible to tell which species it is.

Comment: I am searching more and found a term "Concave Translucent Mushrooms". Still not sure.

Comment: @ar2015 When I use those terms (on a different computer and network to when I wrote my answer) all I get is _Coprinus_ (inkcap group - which used to include the _Parasola_) and _Parasola_ genera coming up.