# Mushroom identification in in a balcony planter in Bavaria

Tags: species-identification, mycology

I've seen the following mushroom pop up in a balkoney planter in **Bavaria (Germany)** in June. They were growing pretty quickly (just in a few days)

### Description

So that others have a chance to find it via Google / text search:

- **Dimensions**: The whole "body" is maybe 3cm high. The "cap" has probably a diameter of 1cm (I can measure it in the evening).
- **Stem**: The stem is smooth and has a bright color.
- **Cap**: Looks like a [cocktail umbrella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_umbrella). It's beige on the top. On the bottom it has dark "stripes" going from the stem to the outside

### Photos

[image]

A picture from the bottom:

[image]

### My research

Google Reverse image search / https://tineye.com/: [Parasola plicatilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasola_plicatilis) - however, I think mushroom are pretty easy to confuse. As this is growing next to food plants I mainly want to know if they are poisonous / how careful one needs to be.

The cap is not transparent as [What is this mushroom attached to the terrarium with transparent cap and black strips?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/107007/)